# opensource feedback loop implementation for email and webmail integration

Tags: email, spam

I would like to find out if there is an opensource software that implements [the Feedback Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_loop_(email)). I will try to be more specific. I want my clients to have the ability to report a message as spam and vice versa and this should be accomplished through a webmail (like roundcube) interface. How can this be implemented based on opensource. My existing email servers are using postfix as mta with clam, amavis and spamassasin and dovecot as imap and pop3 server.

I searched a lot on internet to find out how this feature can implemented and didn't find out anything. I am not sure I understood the idea under Feedback loop, so any help at this point would be appreciated too.

I've searched for similar questions before asking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dovecot have cute little plugin called `antispam` that track messages movements within imap maildir.
When user moves message to/from the "Spam" folder, that plugin invoke some script that perform some specific action. Dovecot config should contain the next section:

```
plugin {
  antispam_backend            = MAILTRAIN
  antispam_spam               = Junk
  antispam_trash              = Trash
  antispam_mail_spam          = --spam
  antispam_mail_notspam       = --ham
  antispam_mail_sendmail_args = 
  antispam_mail_sendmail      = /usr/local/etc/dovecot/mailtrain.sh
. . . . .
```

When user drag some message(s) to/from the "Spam", `mailtrain.sh` script invoked repeatedly with one argument - --spam/--ham correspondingly to the direction. Message body is passed to the stdin of `mailtrain.sh`. Simplest `mailtrain.sh` looks like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
cat <&0 | /usr/local/bin/sa-learn --no-sync $1 2>&1 > /dev/null
exit 0
######
```

As you can see, message is passed to the SpamAssassin's `sa-learn` that learn Bayes analyzer for spam/ham immediately after user moves the message. Keep in mind that `mailtrain.sh` performed with dovecot's uid/gid so you have to ensure that spamassassin have `bayes_file_mode 0666` in the local.cf

Special mention of the "Trash" folder means that training should not be performed when message is moved from the "Spam" folder to the "Trash" - some postmasters moves outdated spam to the trash after some grace period. And that outdated spam shouldn't be learned as ham.

UPD:
I'm absolutely sure you don't want to send claims to the addresses from the "Return-path" header. People whos identities was stolen can't help with spam. So the only rational action - is to learn your bayes.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the above, that got only half of your question:

so, we've figured out a way to identify a movement between spam folders/report as spam. now, one would have to do few remaining things:

1. handle the creation of a valid message that abuse processors (ESPs or other FBL registrants) can read. apparently the standard for feedback loops is ARF messages.
2. handle anonymizing the original message. it is common for the ARF to use a redacted version, to maintain the privacy of your own users when you report the abuse to the FBL registrant.
3. put up an FBL sign up page. an FBL is no good if nobody signs up to the service. you will need some method to verify the ownership of the registrants to avoid someone misrepresenting themselves as an ESP for example.
4. advertise your feedback loop to major ESPs/ISPs.

This is probably something best done by very large companies processing very large amount of mails to be successful.